# Repairing Filesystem in Fedora 12

Tags: boot, fedora

I have installed fedora 12 on my system and now I am having problems repairing the root filesystem. When my system boots up I get this message:

```
***An error occurred during the file system check. 
***Dropping you to a shell; the system will reboot
***when you leave the shell.
Give root password for maintenance
(or type Control-D to continue):
```

When I give the root password to repair filesystem, I get:

```
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell.
(Repair Filesystem) 1#
```

And here I am unable to run fsck command to repair filesystem. What can I do to get this filesystem checked and the system back up and operational?

Comment: Use a livecd to run `fsck` on the filesystem.

Comment: could u plz guide me step my step booting with livecd to fsck command.

Comment: Once the live CD has booted and the GUI has been displayed, open a terminal and switch to root, locate your hard disk's device name (`/dev/...` path), run `fsck /dev/...`.

Comment: i run fsck -A -y /dev/sda and got error   fsck from util-linux-ng 2.16

Comment: What doesvfdisk -l sau? You may want to fsck a partition, not the entire disk, usually, say /dev/sda1 if that is where root is.